# 'System.ValueTuple, Version=0.0.0.0 required for Add-Migration on .NET 4.6.1 Class Library

Tags: entity-framework-core

I upgraded a .net standard class library from Entity Framework Core 1.1 to Entity Framework 2.0

I am trying to run Add-Migration on an Entity Framework Core Class Library that targets .net framework 4.6.1

```
Add-Migration MyMigration
```

But I then get the following error

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.ValueTuple, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'System.ValueTuple, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.SharedTableConvention.Apply(InternalModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelBuilt(InternalModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator validator)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
```

I added the nuget package of `System.ValueTuple` to my csproj but I still get the error

```xml
<PackageReference Include="System.ValueTuple" Version="4.4.0" />
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add `AutoGenerateBindingRedirects` and `GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType` to  your class library csproj

e.g.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>

    ....

    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: so did you change the target framwork of your classs library too? because mine class library project says: <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework> should I change that too?

Comment: No you shouldn't do as my project  target .net framework instead of .net core. Just add the two properties mentioned and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and it got fixed after installing .NET 4.7.1 framework

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the following lovely error because StructureMap failed to instantiate the dbContext for Entity Framework Core:

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type '[NameOfController]'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

I had to do some more work than the answers supplied here to get it to work in .NET Framework 4.6.2:

Install nugets (source: https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp/issues/46)

- System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions (I used latest v4.5.2)
- System.ValueTuple (I used old 4.3.1)

Add to .proj that contained repositories (source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45978409/581414)

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And to web.config (sources: various)

```xml
<configuration>
  ...
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      ...
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.ValueTuple" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.2.0" newVersion="4.0.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  ...
</configuration>
```