# Upgrade EFCore: Could not load file or assembly System.ValueTuple, Version=0.0.0.0

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.0, valuetuple

I'm trying to upgrade EFCore 1.1 to EFCore 2.1

After a long journey of "Could not load assembly" and a bunch of NuGet updates, I'm facing what I think is the last wall before the accomplishment.

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.ValueTuple, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I've tried what I found there:
['System.ValueTuple, Version=0.0.0.0 required for Add-Migration on .NET 4.6.1 Class Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45978173/system-valuetuple-version-0-0-0-0-required-for-add-migration-on-net-4-6-1-cla)

No success.

On the official Git, they propose to add those line in the app.config:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.ValueTuple" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.2.0" newVersion="4.0.2.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

No success either.

If I remove System.ValueTuple from the nuget packages, I have the exact same error.

It's like some dll, I don't know which one, is trying to load the ValueTuple from an unexisting location. I don't even know why it is looking for version 0.

At this point, I have no idea what to do. I've tried tons of stuff I found on the internet, but I'm facing a deadend.

Any help is appreciated.

**Targeted Framework**: 4.7

**EFCore version**: 2.1

**EFCore packages**: Core, Abstractions, Analyzers, Design, InMemory (for test solution), Relational, SqlServer, Tools

**System.ValueTuple**: 4.4.0

**.NetStandard**: 2.0.3

Comment: Try [fuslogvw.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer "Fuslogvw.exe (Assembly Binding Log Viewer)") to see what is trying to load what and why it's failing.

Comment: Hi, I've already tried that but nothing is showing. Logs are enabled. The error occurs in Visual Studio, it's not the yellow page

Comment: fuslogvw.exe has an option to log to file. It should get the info no matter what's trying to load the assembly.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did but nothing is logged... https://imgur.com/h1etEIn

Comment: just ran into this issue with EFCore and adding that dependency fixed my issue